# PowerShell help rename AD user's home directory

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to create a small rename script for AD users with params, like: GivenName, displayname, userPrincipalName, and samaccountname. This is all working fine so fat. But I'm struggling to rename  Home Directory.

The challenge is that users can be on different OU, for example

`\\domain\A\B\C\$samaccountname\documents` or `\\domain\1\2\3\$samaccountname\documents`

How can I rename from `\\domain\A\B\C\$OLD_samaccountname\documents` to `\\domain\A\B\C\$NEW_samaccountname\documents` considering that each user can be on different OU?

Thank you for you help.

Comment: Do you mean to set the new home directory path in the user properties with `Set-ADUSer -Identity $NEW_samaccountname -HomeDirectory "\\domain\A\B\C\$NEW_samaccountname\documents"` or do you mean to rename the home directory folders on the `\\domain\A\B\C` share?

Comment: Are you trying to _rename_ the _directory_ (which only works if it's going to remain on the same file system), or are you trying to _re-set the AD User Object's home directory value_ (which is more-or-less trivial)?

Comment: So far I got as extracting HomeDirectory 

$ADUser = Get-AdUser -Filter {SamAccountName -eq "$AD_old_username"} -Properties HomeDirectory,GivenName,SurName
$ADUser.HomeDirectory | Write-Output

Which gives me path as such: "\\domain\A\B\C\AD_old_username\documents" how can I replace the  AD_old_username with AD_new_username and insert back to homedirectory?

Comment: So Far I have managed to extract the home directory by running 

`$ADUser = Get-AdUser -Filter {SamAccountName -eq "$AD_old_username"} -Properties HomeDirectory,GivenName,SurName
$ADUser.HomeDirectory | Write-Output`

Then I get a path as such:  `\\domain\A\B\C\AD_old_username\documents` now can I replace AD_old_username with AD_new_username and insert back to AD?

Comment: Not sure if this is aright approach but this seems to be working for AD 

`$ADUser = Get-AdUser -Filter {SamAccountName -eq $AD_old_username} -Properties HomeDirectory,GivenName,SurName
 #$ADUser.HomeDirectory | Write-Output

$string = $ADUser.HomeDirectory   
$array = $string -split " "    

$newpath = if($array -match "$AD_old_username") {
    $array -replace "$AD_old_username","$AD_NEW_UserName"
}
#Write-Host "new path is" $newpath
`

How do I change for a share drive?